# SQL WINDOW FUNC when no unique partition

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have this table:

| Date | ID | Product_A_Count | Product_B_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | A | 1 | 2 |

I want to convert it to:

| Start_Date | End_Date | ID | Product_A_Count | Product_B_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | A | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | A | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | A | 1 | 2 |

Is there a way to do it by using just SQL? I've been trying out row_number and lag but none looks right (because the partition by combination of ID, Product_A_Count and Product_B_Count is not unique).

Many thanks for all suggestions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gap-and-islands problem.  In this case, the difference of row numbers is probably the simplest solution:

```
select id, product_a_count, product_b_count, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id, product_a_count, product_b_count order by date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by id, product_a_count, product_b_count, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

There might be simpler solution if, for instance, the dates are all regularly spaced.

Comment: AMAZING! this solves my problem! I'll definitely read more about this technique. Thank you very much for helping!